# Will iAd test ads disappear in Xcode after app approval?

Tags: ios, iad

I'm updating my app and although iAds are still not being served to my app due to its recent approval, the test ads aren't showing anymore in xCode. Will the test advertisements disappear after approval even in the simulator?

Comment: Test ads in development are not affected by the app being live in the store. If neither is showing ads then you probably have a bug in your code.

Comment: they were showing until the app was released

Comment: Did you sign up for iAd support on iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i talked to developer support on the phone and got the answer and the problem has actually been solved today. Once your app is accepted, iAd most likely will not be implemented immediately; and contrary to popular belief this does effect how it shows on your xCode testing as well. Its been about 24 hours since it was accepted and iAd just appeared. So hopefully that can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

iAds are only shown if there are iAds available to be shown. Apple has to sell ads to make them available. I rarely see iAds in my apps. My guess is that there are more people displaying iAds than have been sold.

I use ad AdMob aggregator to show both iAds and Google Ads. Makes beer money that way at least.

Answer (score 0):

He has a thread going in the Apple developer forums as well:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/939808#939808

iAds will show test ads in a debug build on occasion (based on a setting). In the simulator or a test device, you can go into Settings - Developer - and change the Fill Rate or other settings as appropriate if you want to test always or never getting an ad. By default, it's around 50% or so.

Having your app released in the store has nothing to do with the test ads that get displayed in the debug builds not from the store.

So, the issue is most likely a bug in the code if ads, not even test ones, never appear.